# Fcm message doesn't show the attached image

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, push, message

I am testing with API 29, 30 level devices. I'm not sure if it's a policy of Android or something else (Stackoverflow is not allowing me for mentioning the hardware name), but when I send a push notification with image, I sometimes receive messages with no image. It is regarded as if there IS an image, but the message is empty when expanded (There's no problem with texts).

Priority is already set to 'high'
I guess it is a problem of battery saving mode and app standby mode, but I still think the high priority should wake the device up.

Is there any suggestion I could fix the problem?

Comment: confirm this ->
Avoid using images wider than 2000 pixels. Also make sure that your image is not bigger than 1MB.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this document**

Avoid using images wider than 2000 pixels. Also make sure that your image is not bigger than 1MB.

https://help.batch.com/en/articles/3993058-what-is-the-best-image-size-for-my-push-notification

i hope help you

Comment: My pictures are all 460 x 250, and the size is also around 100kb.

Comment: put your FCM class hear